# Why does my Apple TV 4 often turn my receiver off on startup?

Tags: audio, sleep-wake, appletv, hdmi

I have an Apple TV connected via HDMI to a Pioneer VSX-S510 which in turn is connected to my Sony Bravia KDL-32W4000 TV.

I have everything set to power on automatically, and I can control the receiver's volume using the Apple TV remote. When the receiver is off, because I have 'Standby Through' configured on the receiver, the TV plays the audio and I can control its volume using the Apple TV remote.

As expected (and what I want), when I wake up the Apple TV, both the TV and the receiver turn on. However, about half of the time, the receiver powers down again about 3 or 4 seconds after it powers on. Why is that, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: If you have ARC or HDMI-CEC on your TV or receiver, try turning that off.