# Send "soft power off" signal from a Mac via HDMI to a TV

Tags: hdmi, television, appletv

How can I make a TV (a Sony W755C in my case) do a "soft power off" (same as when pressing the ON/OFF on the remote) by sending HDMI signals from a connected Mac?

I think Apple TVs can turn TVs on and off, so then a Mac should theoretically be able too. Is there a command line utility that does this, eg. `hdmitool --soft-power-off`?

PS! This question is a spinoff from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324170/how-do-i-make-macos-properly-blacken-my-tv-screen-on-standby) which has some background on the problem.

Comment: Woot! I have this question too. Looking forward to learning what HDMI protocol allows this remote TV control. Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241950/) one comment says look for ARC or HDMI-CEC

Comment: I don't have an HDMI TV (near my Mac at least) to test, but check these out:  http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libcec and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315372/sending-cec-commands-via-command-line-over-hdmi.  I'm not a fan of HDMI so I typically don't use those cables, but I just might go buy an adapter to see if I can make this work.

Comment: `libcec -l` says "Found devices: NONE". https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/8cg86s/ claims "Macs can't do CEC over HDMI" and you need to buy hardware: https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter. Please let me know if there is any way around this.

Comment: You can't without the adapter: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204388

Comment: @Allan: Augh!! Well, then it's back to the trusty old on/off button. You may post the Apple link as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I make a TV (a Sony W755C in my case) do a "soft power off"
> (same as when pressing the ON/OFF on the remote) by sending HDMI
> signals from a connected Mac?

**Unfortunately, you can't.**

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204388):

> #### Do Mac computers with HDMI support CEC (Consumer Electronics Control)?
>
> Mac computers don't support (and can't control) other devices via CEC
> connections and HDMI.

Basically, the control signals are simply not there to send to your TV.  To do so, you need the [USB adapter](https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter).