# Use the HomePod to turn on TV and Receiver

Tags: appletv, hdmi, siri, homepod

is there any way to have the Apple HomePod control my receiver? Here is what I am thinking:

I would ask the Siri HomePod to play a playlist and Siri would automatically turn on my receiver (Sony STR-DN 1080) and my TV (a Sony Bravia from 2009 that has CEC).

The <s>HomePod</s> Apple TV HDMI is hooked up to my receiver Video 2 port and the TV is hooked up to my receiver’s ARC HDMI port. I do have my Apple TV set to play through my receiver.

I’m hoping I can avoid using remotes altogether to listen to music playlists. Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do to ge it to work?

Comment: I am also looking for similar functionality. Would it be possible using the latest Airplay updates to TVs?

Comment: You’d want to set up Home app scenes and power control / hardware to sequence this. Siri would still launch things, but you’d need home kit scenes and hardware to pull this off. Totally doable, though

Comment: Thanks for the response @bmike Can you recommend some hardware that would help with this?

Comment: Have a look at [meta] on how to ask a separate recommendation question. Maybe one how to turn on power and one for turning on the receiver? It’s hard to answer follow on questions in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.  This cannot be done.**

The HomePod does not have an HDMI interface ([HomePod Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/homepod/specs/)), so consequently, this would be physically impossible to do.

In fact, even [Mac's *with* an HDMI interface don't support the CEC protocol](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/324605/119271).

Incidentally, if you want to connect your HomePod to your Apple TV, this is possible as a (limited) control and as an external audio device.  The latter is self explanatory, so let's look at the former use case as detailed in this [article](https://www.dailydot.com/debug/connect-homepod-apple-tv/).

> When you connect your HomePod to an Apple TV, you can control it only
>   minimally, such as to pause, resume, and adjust the volume. (**You can’t
>   even turn off your Apple TV.**) For more complex voice commands, you
>   must use the Siri Remote.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

If you want to send complex commands to your Apple TV, you'll need the remote (at least at this time).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the HomePod wouldn’t be able to connect with HDMI, but what about turning them on through the Apple TV via Airplay2 or Bluetooth? Apple TV does have an HDMI port.

Comment: That a different question from what was originally asked, but I'll post an update.